# Deforming an approximate algebra into an exact algebra

Tags: matrices, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider a linear subspace of matrices, $M \subset \textrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$, which is $\epsilon$-*approximately* closed under multiplication, i.e. for all $x,y \in M$, there exists $z \in M$ such that $\lVert{xy-z}\rVert < \epsilon \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert$. Assume $M$ is closed under Hermitian adjoints.  Then you might say $M$ forms an "$\epsilon$-approximate" $*$-subalgebra of $\textrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$.  (We might also assume $M \ni 1$ and $M$ is approximately closed under inverses.)

1. Have approximate $*$-subalgebras of this sort been studied? I am familiar with some notions of Ulam stability, approximate homomorphisms, and approximate representations, but the setup here appears slightly different. ($M$ is not given as the image of some approximate homomorphism from an actual algebra.)

In particular, I'm interested in the following:

2. Is it known whether $M$ may be slightly deformed so that it becomes an exact $*$-subalgebra?  E.g., does there exist a subspace $N \subset \textrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ which is an exact $*$-algebra, and which is nearby to the subspace $M$, with distance controlled by $\epsilon$?

---

If anyone's interested, I'll offer an example of a conjecture along these lines. For a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{A}$, call a linear subspace $M \subset \mathcal{A}$ *$\epsilon$-approximately multiplicatively closed* if it is closed under $*$, contains the identity, and satisfies the property that for all $x,y \in M$, $\exists z \in M$ s.t. $\lVert{xy-z}\rVert < \epsilon \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert$.

Also define a distance between two subspaces: for any linear subspaces $X,Y$, let $d(X,Y)$ be the Hausdorff distance between their unit balls.

Then one might conjecture:

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any
> finite-dimensional von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{A}$, for any $\delta$-approximately multiplicatively closed subspace $M \subset \mathcal{A}$, there exists a von Neumann subalgebra $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{A}$ such that $d(M,\mathcal{N})<\epsilon$.

---

The related literature I know seems to focus on *maps* between algebras which are approximately multiplicative, e.g. "[Approximately Multiplicative Maps Between Banach Algebras](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s2-37.2.294)" (Johnson, 1986).  Here, I'm wondering about *linear subspaces* that are approximately multiplicatively closed.  (So these are like "approximate sub-algebras," rather than "approximate homomorphisms.")

Comment: Not that I would know how to answer, but I think you need to make your question more precise. Concretely, what does "nearby... with distance controlleld by $\epsilon$" mean? The problem I see is that if you just require something like the Hausdorff distance, you are not asking $N$ to mimic the pseudo algebraic structure of $M$. So maybe you want a linear isomorphism that is "almost multiplicative"? This sounds more reasonable to me, but then I wouldn't know exactly how to quantify what "almost multiplicative" means.

Comment: Thanks Martin -- I'm asking for the existence of a nearby subspace $N$ that's a true algebra, but without further requiring that $N$ mimics the (approximate) algebraic structure of $M$, except insofar as $N$ is nearby $M$.  That's already a non-trivial request, I think.  Were you suggesting asking for something stronger, or using a stronger assumption?

Comment: I would like to see a concrete meaning for "nearby". Say, why would $N=M_n(\mathbb C)$ not be acceptable?

Comment: Should have said, I edited the question in response to you: by nearby subspaces, I mean they have small Hausdorff distance between their unit balls (in operator norm). Then a proper subspace will not be "close" to the ambient space.

Comment: My bad, I had not seen it.